# web2py GAE connection issue with Google Cloud SQL

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, web2py, google-cloud-sql

Trying to use a web2py application on Google GAE. Database is Google Cloud SQL.
In local test environment, the application works fine but when trying to deploy on GAE + Google Cloud SQL, the data connection fails.

Error in the GAE log:
**'Not authorized to access instance: myapp.appspot.com:instance1'**

The GAE app is granted access to the SQL instance.

Questions:

1. I am not sure the "instance name" is correct. I found "instance 1" in some examples, but where do I find the name of my actual db instance?
2. Is specification of a user name required? (saw "root" being specified in some connection strings), but not on the web2py user manual: which specifies    google:sql://project:instance/database

Comment: Found the answer:  `google:sql://project:instance/database`  is indeed the right syntax, but:     - "project" is only the project ID, as listed in the overview page on google GAE.     - "instance" is the identifier displayed AFTER THE SEMICOLON in the "Cloud SQL" page of GAE.     - "database" is the database name as listed under "Databases" in the GAE "Cloud SQL" page, databases TAB. Default database name is 'mysql'